# If ${b_n}$ is a sequence of non-zero terms that converges to M can not be 0, then there is an $N ∈ N$ such that for all $n ≥ N$, $|b_n| > |M|/2$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If ${b_n}$ is a sequence of non-zero terms that converges to M can not be 0, then there is an $N ∈ N$ such that for all $n ≥ N$, $|b_n| > (|M|)/(2)$.

- The book says to use the Theorem that sates that if ${a_n}$ is a convergent sequence, then ${a_n}$ is a bounded sequence.
- So far I have $|b_n - M|< (|M|) / (2)$ for all $n ≥ N$ then,

$||b_n|-|M||≤|b_n - M|<(|M|)/(2)$

$||b_n|-|M||<(|M|) / (2)$

$(- |M|)/(2)<|b_n|-|M|<(|M|)/(2)$

$|M|-(|M|)/(2)<|b_n|$

$(|M|)/(2)<|b_n|$

- I just do not feel like I am on that right track or that I am missing something and I am also having trouble concluding the proof. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, we know that $\displaystyle b_{n}$ converges to M.

Since $\displaystyle b_{n}$ is convergent, than so is $\displaystyle |b_{n} |$ and it converges to |M|

Consider this convergence from the definition:

$\displaystyle ( \forall \epsilon  >0)( \exists N\in N) \therefore ( \forall n >N) ,||b_{n} |-|M||< \epsilon $

Choose $\displaystyle \epsilon < \frac{|M|}{2}$

This is possible since $\displaystyle M\neq 0$ ⟹ $\displaystyle \frac{|M|}{2}  >0$

Now, we have

$\displaystyle ||b_{n} |-|M||< \epsilon < \frac{|M|}{2}$

$\displaystyle ||b_{n} |-|M||< \frac{|M|}{2}$

$\displaystyle -\frac{|M|}{2} < |b_{n} |-|M|< \frac{|M|}{2}$

$\displaystyle |M|-\frac{|M|}{2} < |b_{n} |< |M|+\frac{|M|}{2}$

⟹$\displaystyle |b_{n} | >|M|-\frac{|M|}{2} =\frac{|M|}{2}$

$\displaystyle |b_{n} | >\frac{|M|}{2} \ \forall n >N$

Proved.